# AdControl not exist in namespace "using: Microsoft.Advertising.WinRT.UI"

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to insert ad in a Windows Phone 8 app using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.
I inserted this code in MainPage.xaml :

```
xmlns:UI="using:Microsoft.Advertising.WinRT.UI"
```

And my Grid tag:

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <UI:AdControl 
        ApplicationId="----------------------" 
        AdUnitId="------" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Height="500" 
        Margin="0,0,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="200"/>
    </Grid>
```

Why do I get this error?

> AdControl not exist in namespace "using: Microsoft.Advertising.WinRT.UI"
>   Errore2 type 'UI: AdControl' not found. Check for missing a reference to an assembly and all assembly to which you refer have been compiled

Comment: Your code above looks correct. Perhaps you are missing a reference as in Mirko's answer.

Comment: @Cherry Bu : please be more careful when editing. The tag you added said "DO NOT USE THIS TAG".

Answer (score 1):

Right click on `Reference` in your `Solution Explorer` window and select `Add Reference`.

**WINDOWS RT (UNIVERSAL APPS)**

Then move on Windows Phone 8.1 Tab and select 'Extensions'. You should find `Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows Phone 8.1 XAML`. Select it and click ok, then rebuild (F6)

**WINDOWS PHONE SILVERLIGHT**

Move on `Assemblies` tab, then click on `Extensions` and add these 2 references:

- Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile
- Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI

Then you have to add in the XAML page this namespace:

```
xmlns:adv="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI;assembly=Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI"
```

and finally add the advertising control to your page:

```
<adv:AdControl ApplicationId="YOUR_APPLICATION_ID" AdUnitId="YOUR_AD_UNIT_ID"
               Width="480" Height="80"/>
```

If you're not able to find references, it's beacuse you didn't install the SDK on your computer. Go [here](http://adsinapps.microsoft.com/en-US/sdk), download the right version according to your needs and install it, then repeat the steps.

Let me know if it works!

Comment: Thank you Mirko! but i have Windows phone 8 app with Adv SDK for windows phone 8 not working. If i switch to Windows phone 8.1 Silverlight App with Windows Ad Mediator (SDK) not working too.

Comment: Ok that makes sense because you're trying to import a SDK which is actually dedicated to the universal app. In order to make things works, download and install the silverlight version of the SDK and repeat the steps above, of course some names will be different, I will post more details ASAP, in the meantime I suggest you to try anyway because steps are very similar (as I said before only some names will change) keep me updated!

Comment: I just updated my answer with the silverlight steps! ;)

Comment: YES it's working! now i see the emulator but i have this exception error: Eccezione first-chance di tipo 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in System.Windows.ni.dll

Ulteriori informazioni: Failed to assign to property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source'. [Line: 13 Position: 44]

Comment: This is a common issue caused by some mistake in XAML.
Can you please post your XAML code with [Pastebin.com](http://www.pastebin.com) ? Thanks

Comment: Hi, here's another possible solution: have you enabled all the required capabilities for advertising? You can find a list of the required ones here at step 3: [link](http://windowsapptutorials.com/windows-phone/advertising/adding-microsoft-pubcenter-ads-in-windows-phone-8-apps/) Also consider to mark my post as the answer if you get things to work! Thanks :)